# R - Match multiple strings while excluding unintended matches

Tags: r, regex

I am extracting weight (grams & kilograms) and volume (millilitres & litres) values from a messy character column in a dataframe but I am unable to exclude the total weights and volumes.

Some sample data looks like this:

```
df <-
rbind(data.frame(text = "199-50 150g4_qty_+ 200g4_qty_"),
      data.frame(text = "chouffe/ 330ml*2_qty_+ 330ml*2_qty_+ 330ml*2_qty_"),
      data.frame(text = "1000g( 500g+ 500g) _qty_"),
      data.frame(text = "(abbott) 900g+50g 2 950g"),
      data.frame(text = "1kg 2kg 3kg 1kg +2kg"),
      data.frame(text = "200ml*18_qty_ +putzi 50ml"),
      data.frame(text = "( 250ml*6_qty_+ 250ml*4_qty_+ 190ml*6_qty_+ 200ml*4_qty_)"),
      data.frame(text = "128g+ 128g+ 128g 384g"))
```

Through a trawl of this site and through trial and error I have written code that extracts the values I want, along with some I do not want.

```
df1 <- regmatches(df$text, gregexpr("\\d+(ml|l|g|kg)", df$text))
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(df1, '[', seq(max(sapply(df1, length))))))
```

I am getting:

```
    V1       V2       V3        V4      V5
1   150g     200g     NA        NA      NA
2   330ml    330ml    330ml     NA      NA
3   1000g    500g     500g      NA      NA
4   900g     50g      950g      NA      NA
5   1kg      2kg      3kg       1kg     2kg
6   200ml    50ml     NA        NA      NA
7   250ml    250ml    190ml     200ml   NA
8   128g     128g     128g      384g    NA
```

which is mostly there but I want to exclude superfluous values such as repeats (row 5) and totals (rows 3, 4 and 8). The end result should be:

```
    V1       V2       V3        V4      
1   150g     200g     NA        NA      
2   330ml    330ml    330ml     NA     
3   500g     500g     NA        NA      
4   900g     50g      NA        NA
5   1kg      2kg      NA        NA
6   200ml    50ml     NA        NA      
7   250ml    250ml    190ml     200ml   
8   128g     128g     128g      NA
```

I have identified that there needs to be a `+` immediately between the values I want to keep. For example, row 3 has a `+` between 500g and 500g so I want to keep both of these values but I do not want to keep the 1000g as there is no `+` between that and the 500g. Similarly, there is no `+` immediately prior to the 384g in row 8.

I just don't know how to use regex to implement this without picking up a `+` from too far away.

Comment: Why does row 5 have no "3kg" and only one "2kg" (the last one has a plus before it)?

Comment: *"I want to exclude superfluous values such as repeats (row 5) and totals (rows 3, 4 and 8)"* How to know if a value is to be excluded? What constitutes a "superfluous value"?

Comment: And why does row 3 have the same value 3 times?

Comment: #Andrew - The raw data is provided in Chinese with Latin numerals and some other characters interspersed. It has already undergone a lot of cleansing and only the Latin characters are retained. The full Chinese data contains a lot more descriptive text, hence the extra values in some cases.

Comment: #Maurits Evers - The superfluous text is any value that is not given in ml, l, g or kg and does not have a "+" on one or both sides. For example, row 3 may have been "Total weight of [in Chinese] 1000g (comprising 500g of shrimp + 500g of squid)"; in which case I want to extract the 500g components without pulling out the 1000g.

Comment: #42 - If you mean row 2, this may have been "Gift pack of beer [in Chinese] with lager 330ml*2 cans + stout 330ml*2 cans + bitter 330ml*2 cans". In this case I am interested in all components as there is no overall total getting in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution after looking at this from many angles has been to remove whitespace around the pluses:

```
df$text <- gsub("\\s+(?=\\+)|(?<=\\+)\\s+", "", df$text, perl=TRUE)
```

Then split the string into elements according to the remaining spaces:

```
var1 <- strsplit(df$text, "\\s+")
```

Then use `grepl` to select the element which contains the pluses, thus removing any elements that do not contain `+`:

```
var2 <- lapply(var1, function(x) x[grepl("\\+", x, perl=TRUE)])
```

And finally use the code as previously created to keep the required strings:

```
df1 <- regmatches(var2, gregexpr("\\d+(ml|l|g|kg)", var2))
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(df1, '[', seq(max(sapply(df1, length))))))
```

This gets me very nearly there with some tinkering around the edges perhaps still required to handle outlier cases.